# Update props of react element rendered from variable

Tags: reactjs

there is a react component stored inside of a state variable. I've attached a sample code and created a [codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-robinson-wz4uf). As you can see, `nameBadgeComponent` is supposed to display `{name}` field from state. It works fine for the default value, but does not react to changes in `name` variable. Is there a way to make it work without updating the `nameBadgeComponent` itself?

```
  const [name, setName] = useState("DefaultName");

  const [nameBadgeComponent] = useState(<h2>My name is: {name}</h2>);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {nameBadgeComponent}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const newName = Math.random()
            .toString(36)
            .substring(3);
          console.log("Renamed to:", newName);
          setName(newName);
        }}
      >
        rename
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a component from a useState. A state  is all the properties and data that define in what condition/appearance/etc the component is. A useState allows to control a piece of information or data, but doesn't respond to changes, a component does.

The fact that you put "Component" in the name should give you a hint ;)

What you want to do is probably this :

```
function NameBadgeComponent({ name }) {
  return <h2>My name is: {name}</h2>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("DefaultName");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NameBadgeComponent name={name} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const newName = Math.random()
            .toString(36)
            .substring(3);
          console.log("Renamed to:", newName);
          setName(newName);
        }}
      >
        rename
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will update to the changes in name properly.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you extracting the nameBadgeComponent to a state? That is useless as it only relies on `name`, keeping your code as close to the original as possible:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState("DefaultName");

const nameBadgeComponent = <h2>My name is: {name}</h2>;

return (
  <div className="App">
    {nameBadgeComponent}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const newName = Math.random()
            .toString(36)
            .substring(3);
          console.log("Renamed to:", newName);
          setName(newName);
        }}
      >
        rename
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Context as to why it does not work: if you use `useState` you are defining the starting state, the code in there is never run again unless you use `setState` (in this case `setNameBadgeComponent`)
Therefore its never updated

EDIT:
The other answer defining the extra component is more reactish code, if you are going to accept an answer accept that one.